# VSIX - Custom collapsing in XML document

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

Is it somehow possible to access the IOutliningTagRegionTag instances, of an open XML document, from within a VSIX extension?
We would like to do some custom collapsing on those regions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do custom collapsing importing [IOutliningManagerService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.outlining.ioutliningmanagerservice?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) and getting [IOutliningManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.outlining.ioutliningmanager?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) from `outliningManagerService.GetOutliningManager(IWpfTextView textView)`.